# SASS compile with comments

Tags: sass, sass-rails

I am compiling a SCSS file and it seems to remove my comments. What command can I use to keep all the comments?

```
>SASS input.scss output.css
```

I see two types of comments in my SCSS.

```
// Comment
```

and

```
/* Comment */
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the two type of comments is pretty easy:

```
// Some comment for a single line
```

and

```
/* This is 
a multiline comment
for large descriptions */
```

According to [the officials docs of SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html#Comments), you can only use the multiline comment option to preserve it into a compiled output file.

> Like Sass, SCSS supports both comments that are preserved in the CSS output and comments that aren't. However, SCSS's comments are significantly more flexible. **It supports standard multiline CSS comments with /* */, which are preserved where possible in the output.** These comments can have whatever formatting you like; Sass will do its best to format them nicely.
>
> **SCSS also uses // for comments that are thrown away**, like Sass. Unlike Sass, though, // comments in SCSS may appear anywhere and last only until the end of the line.

So the following CSS:

```
/* This comment
should be kept
and not be thrown away */
.class {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

// This comment will be thrown away
.extra-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

will be compiled into:

```
/* This comment
should be kept
and not be thrown away */
.class {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.extra-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

To fix your compilation problems, you need to convert the `//` to `/* */` comments.

Answer (score 10):

As @Roy said above, multi-line comments (/* */) are kept in resulted css, but it depends on format you are using to pre-process your SASS.

If you are using **compact mode**, or any other **'CSS minifier'**, you should better use

```
/*! important comment */
```

These comments are kept in the compact(minified) versions of your CSS as well.

Example:

```
html {
     /*! important comment */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Result (compact, minified version):

```
html{/*! important comment */-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
```